# batch file to make backup of modified files only

Tags: batch-file

My requirement is to take backup of only those files which have been modified or created recently.

At this point of time my code is as below. It is picking up the overall xml files in the destination folder under datetime folder.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%A in ('date/t') do (
    set DateDay=%%A
    set DateMonth=%%B
    set DateYear=%%C
)
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%D in ('time/t') do (
    set DateTime=%%D
)
set CurrentDate=%DateDay%-%DateMonth%-%DateYear%-%time:~0,2%.%time:~3,2%
xcopy "D:\Splunk\etc\apps\search\default\data\ui\views\*.xml" "\\cidcswpems2533\d$\backup\%CurrentDate%\"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help of command [xcopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx) output by entering `xcopy /?` in a command prompt window lists a parameter which you have to append here on last line and you are done.

> **/m**
>   Copies source files that have their archive file attributes set. Unlike `/a`, `/m` turns off archive file attributes in the files that are specified in the source.

The archive file attribute is designed for backup processes. Every time a file is created new or modified, the archive attribute is automatically set. Therefore copying just files with archive attribute set and remove it after copy helps you here to copy just the files modified or created since last backup process.